# Python MySQL not refreshing

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mariadb, pymysql

I have two programs: One that fill and updates a database and another that selects info from the database every 10 seconds.

I use Pymysql.

When I update the database I commit the data, I can see the results in the database with command lines, but the other program has the same output and doesn't get the new data!

Do I need to make a special query other than `SELECT`?
Do I need to close the connection and reopen it before all query?

I create the `GetData` class when starting the program and `get_data` is called every 10 seconds.

```
class GetData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    def get_data(self, data):
        with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
            self.sql = "SELECT id_data, somedata FROM mytable WHERE (%s = 'example');"
            cursor.execute(self.sql, (data,))
        return cursor.fetchall()

    def close_conn(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

The program that fills the database:

```
class FillDb:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        #added this line but doesen't help!
        self.conn.autocommit(True)

    def add_in_db(self, data):
        with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
            self.sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (somedata) VALUES (%s);"
            cursor.execute(self.sql, (data,))
            self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: There is no way for us to answer this without seeing some representative code.

Comment: @roganjosh I edited it!

Comment: You cannot parameterize column names. I'm not sure `self.sql = "SELECT id_data, somedata FROM mytable WHERE (%s = "example");"` would work

Comment: I don't  understand what you try to say, but the program works if I restart it, but it doesn't work if it is in a loop

Comment: Please also show us the code that instantiates your classes and calls their methods. I'm with @roganjosh, your SELECT query looks wrong. If `example` is supposed to be astring literal, it should be enclosed in single quotes, and not double quotes in this context. Also, you seem to be calling `fetchall` on a cursor that has already been closed by exiting the contextmanager after calling `execute`; at least based on the indentation shown here. I would expect that `cursor.fetchall` in `get_data` to raise an exception.

Comment: It does exactly the same things with the indentation changes -> `cursor.fetchall` can be called inside and outside the `with self.conn.cursor()`, I get no errors when running the code, but the problem is that I need to close and reopen the connection in the `GetData` class, because if I don't do this I don't get the changes of the database. The exemple was just an typing error. I cannot show the rest of the code, because I call the functions with flask and it would be very big.

Comment: Interesting, looks like they really allow calling `fetchall` on a closed cursor. I have a suspicion though, what happens if you do `with self.conn as cursor:` instead of `with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:`?

Comment: Thank you! It works now! But it is strange that in the documentation of `PyMySQL` they do it with conn.cursor(). Do you know why it works?

Comment: Interested in how and why? I'll write an answer then; this would be too long for a comment. Their docs are not wrong, just .. incomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why you did not see the updates:**

The cause of the behavior is InnoDB's default isolation level [REPEATABLE READ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read). With REPEATABLE READ, the first nonlocking SELECT establishes a snapshot representing the data at that point in time. All consecutive nonlocking SELECTs read from that same snapshot. Updates to the DB from other transactions are not reflected in that snapshot, thus remaining transparent.

Committing the transaction (or closing it and creating a new one) will cause a new snapshot to be created with the next query, representing the data in the DB at *that* point in time. This is how MySQL implements [Consistent Nonlocking Reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html) as part of their [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) compliance strategy.

**Why `with self.conn` works and what it does:**

In PyMySQL, there's two (relevant) contextmanager implementations, one on the [Cursor](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/104e84f5c9c84e5e75bfcad3d23306871c838a8b/pymysql/cursors.py#L64-L69) (more or less 'documented') and one on the [Connection](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/09040abb0a8153b68b76113539632e7eaa53ce69/pymysql/connections.py#L494-L503) (can be found in the code :D).

When you used `with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:` it was the cursor's implementation that was in effect. Entering the context returned `self` (the cursor object returned from the `cursor()` method on `self.conn`); leaving the context ultimately closed that cursor. It has no effect on the transaction.

When using `with self.conn as cursor` it is the connection's implementation that is in effect. Entering the context returns the cursor from calling `self.cursor()`; leaving the context does a `commit` or `rollback` on the transaction. The cursor is closed implicitly as well.

So, the implicit call to `self.commit` when leaving the context of the connection's implementation 'expires' the existing snapshot in your transaction and forces the creation of a new one in the next iteration of your loop, which potentially contains your inserts, as long as their commit has completed before the creation of said new snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the same issue with adding `self.conn.commit()` after

> cursor.fetchall()

Comment: This solution is already provided by [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52386871/5320906).  When answering old questions, please ensure that your answer provides a distinct and valuable contribution to the Q&A.