# Why the script doesn't receive data from mosquitto?

Tags: sql, pymysql, mosquitto, paho, acid

I have following code which receive data from different MQTT topics.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import pymysql
import json
import sys
import time

#-### Constantes ####
PUERTO_MQTT = ...
USUARIO = ...
CLAVE = ...
#DB_LOCAL = ...
DB_LOCAL = ...
RETARDO_SUSCRIP = 30 #s

#-### Variables ####
idsNgsConectados = set()
clienteMQTT = mqtt.Client("receptor_datos_ngs")
db_local = None
t1 = 0
t2 = 0

#-### Funciones ####
def on_connect(clienteMQTT, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Conexion establecida con el broker MQTT correctamente")

def on_message(clienteMQTT, userdata, msg):
    msg_str = msg.payload.decode('utf-8')

    # procesamiento de los mensajes MQTT
    posPrimeraBarra = msg.topic.find('/')

    print("topic: {}".format(msg.topic))
    print("datos: {}".format(msg_str))

    if posPrimeraBarra != -1:
        id_ngs = int(msg.topic[:posPrimeraBarra])
        ref_medicion = msg.topic[posPrimeraBarra+1:]
        variables = json.loads(msg_str)

        if type(variables) is dict:
            if id_ngs in idsNgsConectados:
                try:
                    cursor = db_local.cursor()
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mediciones (id_ngs, referencia) VALUES ({}, '{}')".format(id_ngs, ref_medicion))
                    db_local.commit()
                    cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM mediciones WHERE (id_ngs={} AND referencia='{}') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1".format(id_ngs, ref_medicion))
                    id_medicion = cursor.fetchone()[0]
                    for var in variables:
                        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO valores_mediciones (id_medicion, variable, valor) VALUES ({},'{}',{})".format(id_medicion, var, variables[var]))
                    db_local.commit()
                    cursor.close()
                except Exception as e:
                    db_local.rollback()
                    print("Error 1: fallo el procesamiento de un mensaje MQTT: " + str(e), file=sys.stderr)
                    sys.exit(1)
            else:
                print("Advertencia: un ngs envio datos sin haberse presentado, por lo que se le indicara que salude primero", file=sys.stderr)
                clienteMQTT.publish(str(id_ngs),"saludar",qos=1)
        else:
            print("Advertencia: un ngs envio datos con un formato incorrecto por lo que se le indicara que se reinicie", file=sys.stderr)
            clienteMQTT.publish(str(id_ngs),"reiniciar",qos=1)

def sub_topics():
    global clienteMQTT
    cursor = db_local.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM ngs')
    ids_ngs = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print("Topics suscriptos:")
    for id_ngs in ids_ngs:
        id_ngs = id_ngs[0]
        idsNgsConectados.add(id_ngs)
        topic = str(id_ngs) + '/#'
        print("\t{}".format(topic))
        clienteMQTT.subscribe(topic)

try:
    db_local = pymysql.connect( unix_socket='/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
                    user=USUARIO,
                    password=CLAVE,
                    db=DB_LOCAL )

    clienteMQTT.on_connect = on_connect
    clienteMQTT.on_message = on_message
    clienteMQTT.username_pw_set(username=USUARIO, password=CLAVE)

    clienteMQTT.connect("localhost", PUERTO_MQTT)
    clienteMQTT.loop_start()

    # Bucle infinito
    while True:
        time.sleep(RETARDO_SUSCRIP)
        # Suscripcion a los topics de todos los ngs
        sub_topics()
except Exception as e:
    db_local.close()
    clienteMQTT.loop_stop()
    clienteMQTT.disconnect()
    print("Error 2: desconocido: " + str(e), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(2)
```

The script subscribe dinamically to the topics. If I run the script from the shell it works well, but if a setup it to be run at boot using systemd, it fails. I've setup the unit file to require and to be run after mosquitto, mariadb, dhcpcd and wpa_supplicant services. I'm sure the data is being publish from another device because I can receive it using "mosquitto_sub".
Which could it be the reason?

It runs in a Raspberry pi zero w and the Mosquitto version is 1.5.7.

Comment: By any chance are you reading those constants from environment variables? Or are they hard-coded? If they are environment variables, then you have to make sure that those variables are set in the environment that systemd is using. Also, if you say that the script runs OK when ran manually, then I suspect there's something wrong when running with systemd. Could you expand on how it fails?

Comment: It could be the case that you are developing in some kind of virtual environment that has a different version of `paho-mqtt` than the one installed system-wide and used when running with `systemd`

Comment: Also calling `sub_topics()` every 30seonds isn't going to do anything useful, it should only be called once (probably in the `on_connect()` callback.

Comment: The contants are hard-coded, I've only deleted the values becuase those are private data. I'm not using any environment variable in the code, but maybe paho-mqtt does that, I'll try to get information about that. How could see if systemd is using another version of `paho-mqtt`? Another important detail is that this script isn't directly executed by systemd, but systemd executes a shell script which just execute a python script, called director.py, and this script execute the shown script, using `Popen` of the `subprocess` module.

Comment: This code is intended to receive data from Mosquitto related to different topics, which change in time and that's the reason why I call sub_topics() every 30s to subscribe to the new topics and to resubscribe to the old ones (I implemented the resubscription to see if that could solve the problem), and to store the data in a specific table in a `mariadb` database. The fail consists in the script not storing any data when it is executed through systemd and at the same time I can see the data is being received and deliveres by Mosquitto, using `mosquitto_sub` as client.

Comment: @maurodiamantino it's not clear for me yet where is the script failing. I understand that you are sure that it's being executed, and it does not fail when importing `paho-mqtt`, but it fails when writing to the database?
As far as I know, `systemd` will run stuff as root, so you could try running the script as root, for debugging (`sudo python3 script.py` )

Comment: I would try to start the script manually using `systemctl` and then look for errors and check syslog for errors from systemd. This sounds like an issue debugging systemd and not an MQTT issue.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers. I have good news ... I could find the cause of the problem! And it wasn't because of `mosquitto` or `paho-mqtt`, it was because of `pymysql`. The fail in the code was that I wasn't using the method `commit` in the sql transaction. I'll explain this in more detail in a separated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I could find the cause of the problem and it wasn't because of `mosquitto` or `paho-mqtt`, it was because of `pymysql`. The fail in the code was that I wasn't using the method `commit()` in the sql transaction. That was causing the code to not being able to get the new data that were being introduced by another process in the database. That's because of the InnoDB's default isolation level REPEATABLE READ. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380528/python-mysql-not-refreshing). The correct way to make that sql transaction is the following:

```
def sub_topics():
    cursor = db_local.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM ngs')
    ids_ngs = cursor.fetchall()
    print("Topics suscriptos:")
    for id_ngs in ids_ngs:
        id_ngs = id_ngs[0]
        idsNgsConectados.add(id_ngs)
        topic = str(id_ngs) + '/#'
        print("\t{}".format(topic))
        clienteMQTT.subscribe(topic)
    db_local.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

That data is used by this code to determine which topics it has to subscribe to, and because of that the code wasn't subscribing to the expected topics and so it wasn't receiving the related data from mosquitto.

The `pymysql` documentation doesn't cover that topic, so I recommend to the newbies (I've realizaed that I'm 50% newbie 50% pro jaja) to read about *ACID* and the implementation details of the *RDBMS* that you're using.

Comment: Interesting topic. Nice that you could solve it!